# Redis KeyMiss Notifications Not Firing

Tags: redis

I can see from redis source code that key misses are recorded. 
https://github.com/antirez/redis/blob/1677f4223c6111c5287b58aa171ffc5d5072a47f/src/db.c#L136

[image]

but nowhere in documentation does it say how to use it. 
https://redis.io/topics/notifications

[image]

I have tried listening to all events to no success.

Answer (score 1):

The flag for miss notifications is 'm' - you can find it at around L58 in notify.c. It is still not documented since it exists only in unstable and should be included in the upcoming v6 of Redis.